# Refreshing DB.designer.cs File

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a code base for a website that is in C# and ASP.NET. We're using MySQL to connect to a database that holds token information and data. The code is deployed on a remote server running Windows Server 2008R2. This server does not and cannot have Visual Studio installed on it because I cannot physically access it and it does not have access to the internet, thus all development is done on my local machine and I just svn the code to and from the production server. The server is running MySQL57 and MySQL Workbench 6.2.

The C# code I inherited is connecting to the database by instantiating a DBDataContext which calls the DB.designer.cs file. I recently had to make a change to the database and added a new table and deleted an old unused table.

The problem is that the DB.designer.cs file is auto-generated and I cannot regenerate it to reflect the database changes. I've right-clicked on it and chosen "replace from server", however it is pointing to a nonexistent folder on my local computer and I cannot make it connect to the remote computer. I've deleted it and Visual Studio still refuses to regenerate it. I've tried copying the data from the MySQL Workbench on the server to my computer but it will only output a .sql file and from my searching it appears I need a .dbml file for VS to recognize.

I need to be able to regenerate the DBDesigner file but I don't currently see a way when Visual Studio cannot connect to the database and the database cannot be installed along side Visual Studio. How should I generate this DB.designer.cs file?

Comment: Which methodology use to connect to DataBase? EF?? .....  when you deploy to server no more DB.designer.cs in server, server will contain only compiled .dll, if you publish it again and deploy, server must reflect all changes.... no issue on if you have VS installed on server or not....

Answer (score 0):

I ended up never being able to generate the required file. As I recall, VS was being particularly obstinate about the different versions of connectors and mysql server versions and various things and I simply gave up.

However, I did solve the issue by manually editing the tables from within the dbdesigner file. It took a bit of work and some database research but eventually I was able to get everything working correctly.